# Docker: Best practice for development and production environment

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Suppeose I have a simple node.js app. I can build a container to run the app with a simple Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
CMD node index.js
```

This will copy the source code into the container and I can ship it off to a registry no problem.

But for development I don't want to rebuild the container for every change in my code. So naturally, I use a volume in combination to nodemon. Here's my questions:

- How do I keep the different configurations? Two dockerfiles? Use compose with two different compose files?
- The node_nodules folder on my host is different from the one I need in the container (i.e. some packages are installed globally on the host). Can I exclude it from the volume? If so, I need to run npm install after mounting the volume. How do I do this?

So my question is really: How do I keep dev and deploy environments separate. Two Dockerfiles? Two compose-files? Are there any best practices?

Comment: what is different from development to production? can you use environment  for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the way I handle it is I have 2 Docker files (`Dockerfile` and `Dockerfile.dev`).

In the `Dockerfile.dev` I have:

```
FROM node:6

# Update the repository
RUN apt-get update

# useful tools if need to ssh in or used by other tools
RUN apt-get install -y curl net-tools jq

# app location
ENV ROOT /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

# copy over private npm repo access file
ADD .npmrc /usr/src/app/.npmrc

# set working directory
WORKDIR ${ROOT}

# install packages
RUN npm install

# copy all other files over
COPY . ${ROOT}

# start it up
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

# what port should I have
EXPOSE 3000
```

My NPM scripts look like this

```
"scripts": {
    ....
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/supervisor -e js,json --watch './src/' --no-restart-on error ./index.js",
    "start-production": "node index.js",
    ....
},
```

You will notice it uses supervisor for start so any changes to any file under src will cause it to restart the server without requiring a restart to docker.

Last is the docker compose.

```
dev:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
  volumes:
    - "./src:/usr/src/app/src"
    - "./node_modules:/usr/src/node_modules"
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"

prod:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

So you see in a dev mode it loads and mounts the current directory's `src` folder to the container at `/usr/src/app/src` and also the `node_modules` directory to the `/usr/src/node_modules`.

This makes it so that I can make changes locally and save, the volume will update the container's file, then supervisor will see that change and restart the server.

** Note as it doesn't watch the node_modules folder you have to change another file in the src directory to do the restart **

Answer (score 3):

Use environment variables. See the documentation [Docker env](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/). This is the recommended way, also for use in the production.

Comment: e.g. docker run -e FOO_VAR=$FOO_VAR

Answer (score 1):

You can use single Dockerfile in which you'll just declare `VOLUME` section.

Remember that volume won't get mounted unless you'll specify that **explicitly** during `docker run` with `-v <path>:<path>` option.  Having that given, you can declare multiple `VOLUME`s even in your prod environment.